# Increment and decrement form component with vue issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Please I have been at this for almost three days.

I have been trying to build an increment and decrement reusable component where a value can be passed into it and can be increased and decreased by the touch of a button and the value could be submitted into a form using Vue.

below is my code

parent component

```
<controlinput name="rooms" v-model.number="form.rooms">How many rooms are in the place? </controlinput>
<controlinput name="toilet" v-model.number="form.toilet">How many toilets are in the place? </controlinput>

data() {
    return {
        form: {
            rooms: 0,
            toilet: 0,
        },        
    }
},
```

child component

```
<div class="control">
    <button type="button" class="control-button" @click="decreaseNumber"><img src="~/assets/svg/minus.svg" alt="-"/></button>
    <div class="control-content">
        {{value}}
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="control-button" @click="increaseNumber"><img src="~/assets/svg/plus.svg" alt="+"/></button>
</div>

props: {
    value: {
        default: 0
    }
},
methods: {
    decreaseNumber() {
        console.log('decrease button clicked');
        console.log(this.value--);
    },
    increaseNumber() {
        console.log('increase button clicked');
        console.log(this.value++);
    }
},
```

Please I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) of the docs. If you want to implement a `v-model`, your component needs to take a `value`, and emit an `input` event.

```
methods: {
  decreaseNumber() {
    this.$emit('input', this.value - 1);
  },
  increaseNumber() {
    this.$emit('input', this.value + 1);
  }
}
```

The data (e.g. `rooms`) belongs to the parent. The child component can't modify it directly (e.g. `this.value--`), but can emit an event for the parent to update its data with the correct value.